# shell script to modify part of each line to a new value

Tags: shell, date, datetime

I have a file containing on each line a date time value
I have a command to change all the values to the today date, but i need to be able to change not only to today, but let's say, first 10 lines changed to today, next 10 lines to be changed to yesterday's date, and so on.
Could you please help me on this one?

file snippet:

```
bla|TRANSACTTIME=20181127153310|bla|bla
bla|TRANSACTTIME=20181127153310|bla|bla
bla|TRANSACTTIME=20181127153310|bla|bla
bla|TRANSACTTIME=20181127153310|bla|bla
```

Comment: at least show an example of the file containing date time value

Answer (score 0):

I thinks this should work,

```
#!/bin/bash
set +x

STEP=3            #size of the block you want to modify
DATE_STEP=1       #how many days you want to step
BASEDATE=20181127 #basedate you want to replace

LINES=$(cat $1 | wc -l)
BLOCKS=$((LINES / STEP ))
MODULE=$((LINES % STEP ))
if [ "$MODULE" -ne "0" ];
then
    BLOCKS=$((BLOCKS + 1))
fi

START=1
END=$STEP
ADD_DAYS=0
for i in $(seq 1 $BLOCKS);
do
  NEWDATE=$(date +'%Y%m%d' -d"today+$ADD_DAYS days")

  #sed is used twice, first to get the required lines and then to do the replacement
  sed -n ${START},${END}p $1 | sed s/$BASEDATE/$NEWDATE/

  START=$((END + 1))
  END=$((END + STEP))
  ADD_DAYS=$((ADD_DAYS + DATE_STEP))
done
```

output goes directly to stdout